# Any way to improve the performance for reading a file ,better than buffered reader

Tags: java, io

I am reading a log file through buffered reader mechanism which is taking Total execution time taken in millis: 12944 ,please advise how can I improve the performance and bring down this time , Please advise is nio is more better performance than buffered Reader..!! The file size is of 10MB since it is a log file..!! please advise also how this same thing could be achieved with nio also..!!

```
public class BufferedRedeem
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try
        {
            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://abc.log"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {

            }
            long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

            System.out.println("Total execution time taken in millis: " + elapsedTime);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't print the file to the console. That is where most of your time will be spent. The console is very slow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Or at least don't include the console writing when measuring performance...

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine() includes allocating memory for line as a String and decoding, this also takes time. Try BufferedInputStream.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yeah dude I have removed and now it is taking 218 milliseconds but I want to improve this more..!!

Comment: @PunpunTyagi Are you saying that by removing the `System.out.println` reading the file went from 12,944 ms to 218 ms?  And you still want to improve upon 218 ms?  My math may be off, but reading 10 MB in .218 seconds is ~ 48 MB/second ... that's pretty fast!  The file had to have been cached in your computer's memory to achieve that throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the OP is keen to see how this could be done using NIO.

As the file is small, it is hard to see the difference but it can be measured.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("abc.log");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 1000; i++) {
        pw.println("0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789");
    }
    pw.close();

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    int count2 = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("abc.log"));
    while (br.readLine() != null) count2++;
    br.close();
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.printf("IO: Took %,d ms to read %,d lines%n", time2 / 1000 / 1000, count2);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream("abc.log").getChannel();
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) fc.size());
    fc.read(bb);
    fc.close();
    bb.flip();

    CharBuffer cb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bb.remaining() * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asCharBuffer();
    CharsetDecoder cd = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
    cd.decode(bb, cb, true);
    cb.flip();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    while (cb.remaining() > 0) {
        char ch = cb.get();
        if (isEndOfLine(cb, ch)) {
            // process sb
            count++;
            sb.setLength(0);
        } else {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("NIO as UTF-8: Took %,d ms to read %,d lines%n", time / 1000 / 1000, count);

    long start3 = System.nanoTime();
    FileChannel fc2 = new FileInputStream("abc.log").getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer bb2 = fc2.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc2.size());
    bb.flip();
    StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
    int count3 = 0;
    while (bb2.remaining() > 0) {
        char ch = (char) bb2.get();
        if (isEndOfLine(bb2, ch)) {
            // process sb
            count3++;
            sb3.setLength(0);
        } else {
            sb3.append(ch);
        }
    }
    fc2.close();
    long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start3;
    System.out.printf("NIO as ISO-8859-1: Took %,d ms to read %,d lines%n", time3 / 1000 / 1000, count3);


}

private static boolean isEndOfLine(CharBuffer cb, char ch) {
    if (ch == '\r') {
        if (cb.remaining() >= 1 && cb.get() == '\n') {
            return true;
        }
        cb.position(cb.position() - 1);
        return true;
    } else if (ch == '\n') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isEndOfLine(ByteBuffer bb, char ch) {
    if (ch == '\r') {
        if (bb.remaining() >= 1 && bb.get() == '\n') {
            return true;
        }
        bb.position(bb.position() - 1);
        return true;
    } else if (ch == '\n') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

prints each line is 102 bytes long so the file is ~ 10 MB.

```
IO: Took 112 ms to read 100,000 lines
NIO as UTF-8: Took 207 ms to read 100,000 lines
NIO as ISO-8859-1: Took 87 ms to read 100,000 lines
```

As I mentioned before, its unlikely to be worth the extra complexity of using NIO to save 35 ms.

BTW: If you have a HDD and the file is not in memory, only the speed of your drive will matter.

Comment: @assylias Disappointing to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499479/reading-a-file-through-java-nio has the same homework. :P

Comment: @peter thanks lot it really helped a lot in understanding but what about if I go for memory mapped IO also

Comment: @PunpunTyagi Do you mean like the third example?

Comment: @peter yeah could you please also show how it could be done through memory mapped IO also

Comment: If you use the scroll bar on the code you will see that I have already.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `System.out.println(sCurrentLine);` inside your loop this is usually **VERY** inefficient as it basically involves flushing the output in *every* call.

Can you try just putting the lines in a ArrayList instead of outputting then and measuring that time? Does it spend a similiar amount of time that way?

Comment: thanks a lot I have updated my post as file size is of 10 mb , Please advise better way than buffered reader

Comment: @PunpunTyagi You should be able to read a 10 MB text file with BufferedReader in less than 250 ms. You can make it much fast with a faster drive and NIO but that adds complexity/cost. What is your performance requirement?

Comment: @Punpun Tyagi I am pretty sure that reading 10Mb with a `BufferedReader` does not consume 13 seconds on current hardware. Please measure performance without using `System.out` (write to a `BufferedWriter`), or at least redirect output to a file when invoking your application (as in `myapp > myoutput.txt`)

Comment: @PeterLawrey can you show me how this same thing could be achieved through java NIO..!!

Comment: @PunpunTyagi Can you show me you actually need it? I have shown NIO examples to people before but they find it needlessly complex and realise they didn't need it in the first place. I don't want to be wasting any ones time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I request you if you could convert my above code in NIO so that will make understanding more clear

Answer (score 0):

Your execution time is mostly due to the `System.out.println(sCurrentLine);`. Instead of just sysout i assume you would want to do some processing or filtering.

If you want to check the speed of BufferedReader use a counter to count the number of lines read and just print the count.

Comment: ..could you please update and post that how this thing could be achieved..!!

Comment: You have got the time as 218ms for a 10MB file.. you want to make it faster ?!

Comment: yeah that what I am trying , Please advise does memory mapped IO or NIO will help me to bring it down..!!

Answer (score 0):

> The file size is of 10MB since it is a log file

Then if you have a decent computer, reading the whole file at once should not be an issue (requires Java 7):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/temp/test.log"), Charset.
                forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Lines read: " + lines.size());
        System.out.println("Total execution time taken in millis: "
                + ((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note: reading a 6MB file takes 75 ms on my computer with that method.

Comment: could you please post the complete code that will make understanding more clear

Comment: @PunpunTyagi That is the complete code. It does the same thing as your code in one line (and puts all the lines in a `List` - so you can do what you want with them).

Comment: @PunpunTyagi I have added a complete example.

Comment: thanks dude I have to install seprate java7 for this also..!!thanks a lot..!! :)