# Reading a file through java NIO

Tags: java, io, nio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to improve the performance for reading a file ,better than buffered reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498731/any-way-to-improve-the-performance-for-reading-a-file-better-than-buffered-read)

I was reading a file named ty.log which is of 20 mb through buffered reader please advise how to read the same thing through NIO ..Below is my program please advise me how to convert so that the same file I can read through java nio also under jdk 1.6

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    BufferedReader br = null;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try
    {
        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://ty.log"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {

        }
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

        System.out.println("Total execution time taken in millis: " + elapsedTime);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only an exact duplicate but I suspect the same `[homework]` ?! The formatting is better though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For reading files using nio you can use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel`

class.
[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) explains it all.