# Array of an List?

Tags: java

I have this code where I have an list of each sentence from the scanned text file, and it prints the sentences that end with ; and ,   And I'm wondering if I could make another array of each word in each sentence, so that I can scan the words instead of the sentences?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("amazing.txt")); 
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

        while (sf.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            String current = sf.nextLine(); 
            if (current.endsWith(",") || current.endsWith(";") || current.endsWith("!"))
                System.out.println(current);
        }
        sf.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to `split` a string into array of words.

Comment: Your code does not seem to involve arrays at all. Perhaps you meant List?

Comment: *"I have an array of each sentence"* No you don't. You have a `List` with each *line*. You don't have an array, and a line of text is not the same as a sentence. Besides, you don't have anything, because you never add anything to `text`.

Comment: @Andreas he is trying to `print` it out each time , so in case he manages to get a word without special characters he will add it to the `List` although i agree with you, the title as well as the question has to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we don't use `Scanner` Object to read a file as it's not a `Best Practice` check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498731/any-way-to-improve-the-performance-for-reading-a-file-better-than-buffered-read) as @Zabuzard pointed out .

**Solution:**

```java
 Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("amazing.txt"));
 List < String > text = new ArrayList < > ();

 while (sf.hasNextLine()) {
  String current = sf.nextLine();
  //  if (current.endsWith(",") || current.endsWith(";") || current.endsWith("!"))
  //  System.out.println(current);

  String all_words[];
  all_words = current.split(" "); //create an array with all strings seperated with space for each line
  System.out.print("All words of the line:");
  for (int i = 0; i < all_words.length; i++) {

   System.out.print(all_words[i] + " ");
  //after you do in this section your checks, add it to the List
  }
  System.out.println();

 }
 sf.close();
```

This will print all the words of each line. You can continue on with implementing your login in your case scenario and `trim` the strings to remove the special characters as well.

Then you can proceed by adding it to your `List<String>`.

Comment: If you want to recommend a modern way to read files then promote NIO (since Java 8). `BufferedReader` is also *outdated* (for many tasks).

Comment: @Zabuzard didn't know about it, thank you very much for commenting , i'll go ahead and edit it!  thanks!